# I want to collate ID of Login ID and Pass with a table with Visual Web Developer 2008

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I'm very beginner for developping.

environment is ..

- Windows XP Professional SP3 Microsoft
- Visual Web Developer 2008 Express
- Edition Microsoft SQL Server 2008

[table_name:LOGIN]

- login_id　-> 　char(5）
- login_name　->nchar(20)
- password 　->　char(10)

My Question is following.

- How to develop login program ? with  the table
- I want to distribute a page opening after login by one charactor of head of the login ID (five charactores)
- Do error indication three times when user failed in login

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [this walkthrough](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/879kf95c(VS.80).aspx) for visual web developer.  There are a ton of great walthroughs in [Getting Started (How Do I in Visual Web Developer)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186109(VS.80).aspx).